# How to get user entered data from datagridview to windows forms diagram?

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, datagridview

I'm trying to get the user entered data in a windows forms datagridview to a windows forms diagram but I have no idea how to do it. I don't even know how to get the user entered data out of the datagridview.

I've been trying to set up a local database in Visual Studio but i'm using C++ and the support for databases in VC++ 2010 seems to be removed. I have also tried to set up a SQLite database, but without success.

**Is there a way to get the user entered data from the datagridview to the diagram without using a database or with using some other database than Microsofts option?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been looking over the same problem, try this-> http://www.functionx.com/vccli/controls/dgv.htm , let me me know if it helps

Edit:

### This is just the code I posted below put in the Original Answer and better formatted:

I have been working on this problem at the same time. what I got to work editing the value:

`System::String^ dur; 
this->dataGridView1->Rows[1]->Cells[1]->Value = dur;`

and this will give the value in the data grid:

```
 System::String^ foo;
 foo = (System::String^)this->dataGridView1->Rows[1]->Cells[1]->Value;
```

this will give the value also, but you cannot edit it:

`System::String^ derp;

this->dataGridView1->CurrentCell = this->dataGridView1[1,1];

derp = (System::String^)this->dataGridView1->CurrentCell->Value;`

Have not tried writing or reading from

```
this->dataGridView1[1,1]->View;
```

but I think that might work, too .

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. It helped on some aspects, I now have a deeper insight in how the datagridview works and I've learned how to change the data in specific rows and columns. But from what I could tell the info in the link did not tell how to get user entered data out of the datagrid and into a diagram or how to store it in variabels or arrays.

Comment: @Kersch Okay, I have been working on this problem at the same time. what I got to work was ---
System::String^ dur;
this->dataGridView1->Rows[1]->Cells[1]->Value = dur;
----
and this will edit what is there
----------
System::String^ foo;
foo = (System::String^)this->dataGridView1->Rows[1]->Cells[1]->Value;
-------
this will take the value
also
-------
System::String^ derp;
this->dataGridView1->CurrentCell = this->dataGridView1[1,1];
derp = (System::String^)this->dataGridView1->CurrentCell->Value;
------------ 
will also take the value but you cannot write to it.

Comment: @Kersch Have not tried writing or reading from this->dataGridView1[1,1]->View; but I think that might work too

Comment: I'll try using the lines that you wrote above. I'll be back to comment after I've tried it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I'm now able to get the data out of the datagridview without using a database!